# Rails 3 and Ajax interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm a beginner in ruby on rails and I was practicing Ajax but unfortunately I can't seem to get my ajax to work. I'm trying to Ajaxify my delete in the scaffold.

Here's my controller:

```
class PlantsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /plants
  # GET /plants.json
  def index
    @plants = Plant.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html #index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @plants }
    end
  end

  # GET /plants/1
  # GET /plants/1.json
  def show
    @plant = Plant.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @plant }
    end
  end

  # GET /plants/new
  # GET /plants/new.json
  def new
    @plant = Plant.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @plant }
    end
  end

  # GET /plants/1/edit
  def edit
    @plant = Plant.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /plants
  # POST /plants.json
  def create
    @plant = Plant.new(params[:plant])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @plant.save
        format.html { redirect_to @plant, notice: 'Plant was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @plant, status: :created, location: @plant }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @plant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /plants/1
  # PUT /plants/1.json
  def update
    @plant = Plant.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @plant.update_attributes(params[:plant])
        format.html { redirect_to @plant, notice: 'Plant was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @plant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /plants/1
  # DELETE /plants/1.json
  def destroy
    # binding.pry
    @plant = Plant.find(params[:id])
    @plant.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to plants_url }
      format.js
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the view for it:

```
<h1>Listing plants</h1>

<table class="show">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<%= render "plants/plant" %>

</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Plant', new_plant_path %>
```

here's my partial:

```
<% @plants.each do |plant| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= plant.name %></td>
    <td><%= plant.comment %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', plant %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_plant_path(plant) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', plant, confirm: 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :remote => true %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

and lastly, here's the supposed destroy.js.erb that would refresh the DOM:

```
$('.show').html("<%= render @plant %>");
```

Anyone can shine a light on this please?

Additional Info:

The thing is, when I click the `Destroy` link... The record is being deleted, but the DOM isn't rendering and I have to refresh to see the changes :(

Comment: I think your controller needs a "format.js" that is called on "Destroy". I'm new to Rails too, but I'd try:
 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @plant }
    end

Comment: Hey friend, I have the 'format.js', just scroll down a bit and you'll see it's define in my controller :)

Comment: Oh! I didn't notice the scrollbar. Sorry, not enough sleep :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a grueling night of thinking and eating here's the solution I have formulated.

First I will describe the root of my problem. It seems that this piece of code `$('.show').html("<%= render @plant %>")`, rails is trying to render route '/plants/:id/' but unfortunately, you just deleted it. The work around I made is to add `@plants = Plant.all` below the `@plant.destroy` code and in the `destroy.js.erb` i rendered the partial and it goes something like this:

```
$('.show').html("<%= render 'plants/plant' %>");
```

with that code, it will render the partial with the new set of queries values. Hopefully I explained it right.

Answer (score 0):

Upon multiple trials I have tried a new tutorial which works fine for me. The link of the tutorial is at the bottom. I will still update this post if ever I found out the solution of this question.

tutorial link ---> [Link here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/)